# Vapor 3: Using multiple databases

Tags: database, vapor

Using Vapor 3, is there an easy way to switch databases, while the server is running?

For example, a user logs in using the 'login' db. I then set 
the db for that user in their cookie. Any subsequent requests from that user then use the db identified in the cookie (the 'user' in this scenario would really be a company).

All db's would be from the same db family (eg MySQL). 
This would keep every companies data in their own db, and limit
the size of each db (and hopefully, overall, db operations would be faster).
Also, any need to restore a db would only impact one company, and backups would be simpler.

1. How to achieve this?
2. Would this be very inefficient?

Are there other better ways to achieve this?

Answer (score 7):

As far as I understand you could create some different database identifiers like:

```swift
extension DatabaseIdentifier {
    static var db1: DatabaseIdentifier<MySQLDatabase> {
        return .init("db1")
    }
    static var db2: DatabaseIdentifier< MySQLDatabase > {
        return .init("db2")
    }
}
```

and then register them in `configure.swift` like this

```swift
let db1 = MySQLDatabase(config: MySQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", username: "root", database: "db1"))
let db2 = MySQLDatabase(config: MySQLDatabaseConfig(hostname: "localhost", username: "root", database: "db2"))
var databaseConfig = DatabasesConfig()
databaseConfig.add(database: db1, as: .db1)
databaseConfig.add(database: db2, as: .db2)
services.register(databaseConfig)
```

after that don't forget to use `.db1` and `.db2` identifiers everywhere instead of default `.mysql` (for MySQL), e.g. in migrations

```swift
migrations.add(model: User.self, database: .db1)
```

with pooled connections

```swift
return req.requestPooledConnection(to: . db1).flatMap { conn in
    defer { try? req.releasePooledConnection(conn, to: . db1) }
    return User.query(on: conn).all()
}
```

and in transactions

```swift
return req.transaction(on: .db1) { conn in
    return User.query(on: conn).all()
}
```

Sorry if I haven't answered your questions. I understand that it'd be great if `Fluent` could support passing database name for each query, but I haven't found that in it. (or it's not obvious how to pass database name on query)

But btw from my point of view having separate databases for each client may give you a real headache on migrations... maybe it'd be better to store them all in one database but with partitioning? e.g. for PostgreSQL like [described here](https://severalnines.com/blog/guide-partitioning-data-postgresql)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The need to have separate dbs is a requirement of the security policies of the companies, not just for performance.

I don't quite understand your transactions bit. I have routes set up, and am not clear how I would use a different db in the route.

Comment: It might also be benificial to take a microservices architecture into consideration.

Comment: Nvm they’re all part of the same DB family ignore what I just said :)

Comment: Oh, as far as I understand all your queries now seems look like User.query(on: req)

Comment: Unfortunately in this construction it's not possible to specify database identifier

Comment: So you could get pooled connection with your custom database identifier and then run your query on that connection instead like User.query(on: conn)

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer, I've added an example for pooled connection